# Merging dataframes keeping all items pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge

How can I merge two different dataframes, keeping all rows from each dataframe while filling in the blanks?

DF1

```
Name     Addr      Num     Parent   Parent_Addr
Matt     123H      8       James    543F
Adam     213H      9       James    543F
James    321H      10      Mom      654F
Andrew   512F      10      Dad      665F
Faith    555A      7       None     657F
```

DF2

```
Name     Parent    Parent_Num  Parent_Addr
Matt     James     10          543F
Adam     James     10          543F
James    Mom       12          654F
None     Ian       13          656F
None     None      None        1234
```

Expected output

```
Name     Addr      Num     Parent   Parent_Num   Parent_Addr  
Matt     123H      8       James    10           543F
Adam     213H      9       James    10           543F
James    321H      10      Mom      12           654F
Andrew   512F      10      Dad      None         665F
Faith    555A      7       None     None         657F
None     None      None    Ian      13           656F
None     None      None    None     None         1234
```

I am attempting to merge and keep all data from both dataframes. Any help would be greatly appreciated. THank you.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to merge on all the common columns and use outer join

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on = ['Name', 'Parent', 'Parent_Addr'], how = 'outer')

    Name    Addr    Num Parent  Parent_Addr Parent_Num
0   Matt    123H    8   James   543F        10
1   Adam    213H    9   James   543F        10
2   James   321H    10  Mom     654F        12
3   Andrew  512F    10  Dad     665F        NaN
4   Faith   555A    7   None    657F        NaN
5   None    NaN     NaN Ian     656F        13
6   None    NaN     NaN None    1234        None
```

Comment: Is the on list expected to be all columns that are the same between the two dataframes? I see you only have three columns specified and am new to the merging.

Answer (score 4):

You can keep all the rows with an `'outer'` `merge`
*note* that by default `merge` will join on all common column names.

```
df1.merge(df2, 'outer')

     Name  Addr   Num Parent Parent_Addr Parent_Num
0    Matt  123H   8.0  James        543F         10
1    Adam  213H   9.0  James        543F         10
2   James  321H  10.0    Mom        654F         12
3  Andrew  512F  10.0    Dad        665F        NaN
4   Faith  555A   7.0   None        657F        NaN
5    None   NaN   NaN    Ian        656F         13
6    None   NaN   NaN   None        1234       None
```