# erratic behaviour with df.merge pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge

I want to keep rows from both dataframes that I'm merging and then remove duplicates (keeping the first record)

wrote the following code:

```
dfSPP0 = dfSPP0.merge(dfCQP0, how = 'outer')
dfSPP0 = dfSPP0.drop_duplicates(subset=['Application_Number', 'PA'], keep='first')
```

In the process of checking my work, I noticed that not all identical records are merged (see first two rows and rows 5 and 6). You're seeing all the columns in both data frames.

Based on what I read I also didn't expect any duplicate records to be deleted.

Is my code poorly written causing the erratic behaviour? If not any thoughts on why this is happening. thanks

[image: records in both dataframes]

Comment: I want to add that when I ran the second line of the code above to remove duplicates, the first 6 records still remained. But the other two duplicates (203 and 7146; 227 and 7147) got reduced. Application number is trimmed before any of the above code is run and there's no hidden spaces.

Also when I copied the data over to excel and ran 'remove duplicates' it cleaned the first six records.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to comment.

I think you should specify the column or index level names to join on? If `on` (or `right_on`, `left_on`) is `None` and not merging on indexes then this defaults to the intersection of the columns in both DataFrames. Click [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for more information.

Comment: thanks. I don't think columns need to be specified when you're using all the columns for the merge as per below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42940507/merging-dataframes-keeping-all-items-pandas#42940540

the same is in the documentation >> _onlabel or list: ...These must be found in both DataFrames. If on is None and not merging on indexes then this **defaults to the intersection of the columns in both DataFrames**._

Comment: Yeah, if you use the intersection of the columns in both DataFrames, it is okay without any columns specified. Can you mail some sample files to me? I'm curious about it. Email: bingli018@gmail.com